# TELEPOT Keep getting error 400 when chat not found when trying to call back query to send a message

Tags: python, bots, telepot

This is my code, my conf.py file is just the API token which i have double checked and the timezone.
I am trying to get my bot to respond to a button click by sending a message or a photo. I understand i need to use the sendPhoto function but i dont know how to make it activate on the callback

```
import sys
import time
import os
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from telepot.namedtuple import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telepot.delegate import (
    per_chat_id, create_open, pave_event_space, include_callback_query_chat_id)

def on_chat_message(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)

    if content_type == 'text':
        if msg['text'] == '/start':
           bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Welcome to @UK_Cali Teleshop\n      Created by JonSnow 2021',reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
                                    [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Feedback",callback_data='a'), InlineKeyboardButton(text="You",callback_data='b'),InlineKeyboardButton(text="PGP",callback_data='c'), InlineKeyboardButton(text="Cunt",callback_data='d')],
                                    [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Products",callback_data='e')]
                                ]
                                ))
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Quanti anni hai?', reply_markup=keyboard)
def on_callback_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')
    print('Callback Query:', query_id, from_id, query_data)

    if query_data=='a':
        bot.sendMessage(query_id, 'ddd')



    

bot = telepot.Bot('1646167995:AAGsOwfjcryYYkoah69QJ6XGA7koUywmuRk')
MessageLoop(bot, {'chat': on_chat_message,
                  'callback_query': on_callback_query}).run_as_thread()
print('Listening ...')

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

you get your 400 error because the chat id  is not `quesry_id` that represents the query, but `from_id` that represents the chat so:

```
def on_callback_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')
    print('Callback Query:', query_id, from_id, query_data)

    if query_data=='a':
        bot.sendMessage(from_id, 'ddd')
```